# How to configure Maven to run tests after it starts tomcat server?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee, junit

When I run my maven project, it starts with the tests, and they all fail because tomcat server hasn't started yet and the war hasn't been deployed?
How can I configure maven to when testing to:

Start the server/application --> then run the tests --> then stop the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Tomcat Maven Plugin to run tomcat during build. 
Try following configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- excludes tests that require application -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/TomcatPingTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- starts tomcat before test execution and stops after-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-tomcat</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-tomcat</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shutdown</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <port>5555</port>
                <path>/app</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- runs tests -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/TomcatPingTest.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```